# my bootstrap navbar code is not working : how can ı fix

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

For whatever reason, it doesn't seem like my HTML doc is linking to the Bootstrap stylesheet. I used one of their dropdown code snippets, but the end result isn't stylized. Can someone see if I'm doing something wrong? Below is my HTML code.

**where is my fault**

> drop down menu does not work

> I use bootstrap5

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>yönetim paneli</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../imgs/logo.png" width="100px"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                                <a class="active nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Yazarlar
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yeni Ekle</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tüm Yazarlar</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a couple of `li` and other important Bootstrap classes. Make sure to match Bootstraps docs with your own work

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>yönetim paneli</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../imgs/logo.png" width="100px"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Yazarlar
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yeni Ekle</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tüm Yazarlar</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```